# Sum of 4 fields in table with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.6

I need to find sum of 4 table field values of each customer id but i'm getting total of all customerid,i need sum of each customerid

```
 $vehpaymenthtry = Stock::join('bookings', 'bookings.chasis_no', '=', 'stocks.frame_no')
            ->join('branches', 'branches.branch_id', '=', 'bookings.branch_id')
            ->join('amounts', 'amounts.customer_id', '=', 'bookings.customer_id')
            ->select(DB::raw("SUM(finance_amount+cash+cheque_dd+exchange_amount) as totalpayable") ,'bookings.created_at', 'bookings.customer_id', 'bookings.customer_name', 'stocks.model_variant', 'branches.name as brname', 'stocks.color', 'stocks.frame_no', 'stocks.engine_no')
            ->whereDate('bookings.created_at', '>=', $request->input('fromdate'))
            ->whereDate('bookings.created_at', '<=', $request->input('todate'))
            ->where([['amounts.status', '=', 0],['branches.status', 0]])->get();
```

here is the result screenshot

[image]

And Database Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group by `customer_id`
something like this:

```
   $vehpaymenthtry = Stock::join('bookings', 'bookings.chasis_no', '=', 'stocks.frame_no')
        ->join('branches', 'branches.branch_id', '=', 'bookings.branch_id')
        ->join('amounts', 'amounts.customer_id', '=', 'bookings.customer_id')
        ->select(DB::raw("SUM(finance_amount+cash+cheque_dd+exchange_amount) as totalpayable") ,'bookings.created_at', 'bookings.customer_id', 'bookings.customer_name', 'stocks.model_variant', 'branches.name as brname', 'stocks.color', 'stocks.frame_no', 'stocks.engine_no')
        ->whereDate('bookings.created_at', '>=', $request->input('fromdate'))
        ->whereDate('bookings.created_at', '<=', $request->input('todate'))
        ->where([['amounts.status', '=', 0],['branches.status', 0]])->groupBy('bookings.customer_id')->get();
```